# ECSliding, calling topViewController warning

Tags: objective-c, warnings, ecslidingviewcontroller

I'm using ECSliding and I have this problem!

In my project there are this files:

```
FirstViewController(UIViewController) (topViewController)
LefViewController(UIViewController) (underLeftController)
```

I do this in my `LeftViewController` because I need to call a timer that is in `FirstViewController`:

```
FirstViewController *first = self.slidingViewController.topViewController;
```

and I get this warning:

```
Incompatible pointer types initializing 'FirstViewController *_strong' with an expression of type 'UIViewController *'
```

everything works fine but if it possibile I would like to get rid of it.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a cast:

```
FirstViewController *first = (FirstViewController *)self.slidingViewController.topViewController;
```

This tells the compiler "trust me, it's a `FirstViewController` instance". If it isn't when you come to run the code you'll get an exception.